# display the page source of a web page in php

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping

How do i retrieve the entire page source info   of a particular web page in a string variable and echo it  in php. i am new to php and have no idea of doing so can any one give me  the complete source code of it.
Following is my source code:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHtmlFile('http://www.google.com');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$elements = $xpath->query('//input[@name="session_id"]');
if ($elements->length) {
    echo "found: ", $elements->item(0)->getAttribute('value');
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
}
?>
```

I have replaced the above code with

just changed the url to:
'http://www.flipkart.com/professional-android-2-application-development-8126525894/p/itmdytmwpjzyhade?pid=9788126525898&ref=8a47bf68-7558-43ce-a9b2-17c1ac119e84'

but it gives the following error:
**Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.flipkart.com/professional-android-2-application-development-8126525894/p/itmdytmwpjzyhade?pid=9788126525898&ref=8a47bf68-7558-43ce-a9b2-17c1ac119e84) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  in C:\wamp\www\displaycontentswebpage.php on line 2**

Expected Result:(Page source)

```
<title>Professional Android 2 Application Development 8126525894: Book: Reto Meier (9788126525898) | Flipkart.com</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
<!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" /> -->
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="102988293558" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="658873552,1412400758,624500995,100000233612389"/>
<meta name="Keywords" content="professional android 2 application development, buy professional android 2 application development, professional android 2 application development india, professional android 2 application development review, reto meier, 8126525894, 9788126525898" />
<meta name="Description" content="Professional Android 2 Application Development by Reto Meier. Rs.449, Save 25%. Buy Professional Android 2 Application Development, All India Free Home Delivery. 8126525894, 9788126525898 |" />


    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.flipkart.com/professional-android-2-application-development-8126525894/p/itmdytmwpjzyhade" />
<link rel='shortcut icon' href='http://img5.flixcart.com/www/prod/images/favicon-18354.ico' />................something something..........................




src="http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/1017598645/?value=0&amp;label=9tgBCLOv-QIQtaWd5QM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
                </div>
            </noscript></div>
```

Kindly help.

Comment: if i use www.google.com or www.flipkart.com it works fine but if i go to a specific page say in flipkart like this http://www.flipkart.com/professional-android-2-application-development-8126525894/p/itmdytmwpjzyhade?pid=9788126525898&ref=732e717b-1de4-49d8-857f-7798b836b6f4          it does not work. plz help as i am new in php and have no idea abt this.

Answer (score 1):

As you have loaded the document in the `$dom` variable, you can do:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($dom->saveHTML());
```

See the manual for [`saveHTML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php)

I am using `htmlspecialchars` so that the html will be displayed instead of rendered.

Comment: the error is as follows : Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.flipkart.com/professional-android-2-application-development-8126525894/p/itmdytmwpjzyhade?pid=9788126525898&ref=732e717b-1de4-49d8-857f-7798b836b6f4) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! <html> in C:\wamp\www\displaycontentswebpage.php on line 3

Notice: Use of undefined constant ENT_SUBSTITUTE - assumed 'ENT_SUBSTITUTE' in C:\wamp\www\displaycontentswebpage.php on line 3

Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in C:\wamp\www\displaycontentswebpage.php on line3

Answer (score 0):

That is achieved via a single function in PHP `file_get_contents()` (http://php.net/file-get-contents) This returns the contents of a file as string.

```
// print source to current output
echo file_get_contents( 'http://www.google.com' );

// print content as readble format
echo htmlspecialchars( file_get_contents( 'http://www.google.com' ), ENT_SUBSTITUTE );
```

The `ENT_SUBSTITUTE`- or `ENT_IGNORE`-flag is necessary for `htmlspecialchars()` if the input contains an invalid code unit sequence within the given encoding. See http://php.net/htmlspecialchars#refsect1-function.htmlspecialchars-returnvalues

Comment: www.google.com or www.flipkart.com gives proper values but a specific page  like    this         http://www.flipkart.com/professional-android-2-application-development-8126525894/p/itmdytmwpjzyhade?pid=9788126525898&ref=732e717b-1de4-49d8-857f-7798b836b6f4                   gives error. please help

Comment: @user1278731 The error is within `htmlspecialchars()`: there must be a character within the input, that does not belong to the used encoding. I'll update the answer…

Comment: waiting for your answer.Thanks

Comment: i have tried above code as well  <?php

echo htmlspecialchars( file_get_contents( 'http://www.flipkart.com/professional-android-2-application-development-8126525894/p/itmdytmwpjzyhade?pid=9788126525898&ref=732e717b-1de4-49d8-857f-7798b836b6f4' ), ENT_SUBSTITUTE );
?>   but it still gives error

Comment: the error is as follows : Warning: file_get_contents(flipkart.com/…) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! <html> in C:\wamp\www\displaycontentswebpage.php on line 3 Notice: Use of undefined constant ENT_SUBSTITUTE - assumed 'ENT_SUBSTITUTE' in C:\wamp\www\displaycontentswebpage.php on line 3 Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in C:\wamp\www\displaycontentswebpage.php on line3

Comment: `ENT_SUBSTITUT` is PHP 5.4; `ENT_IGNORE` is similar and available since PHP 5.3. The other error "HTTP request failed" is caused by something different. (PHP- or Proxy-settings?)

Answer (score 0):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument ('1.0');

@$dom->loadHTMLfile ('https://mp3skull.cr');

$thisi=$dom->saveHTML();

echo htmlentities($thisi);
```

this will print the html source of the page